# What does branobilis/braenobilis mean?

Tags: palaeography, 18th-century, church-records, latin

I have a baptismal entry (http://data.matricula-online.eu/en/oesterreich/gurk/st-peter-im-katschtal/S65_003-1/?pg=88, 3. from the top) that I cannot reproduce here due to the CC-BY-NC-ND license which appears to read

> Joannis Peyrer Graff Lodronsch Wasch-Huettner et Maria Grieshoferin uxoris filii legitii heri vespere 3tia natii mane 9na baptizatii fuit a. R D Francisco Hödlmayr coadt. levante braenobili juvene Vincentio Fererio de Herisch filiufam supremi telonarii

Regarding the godfather - the son of a customs official named Vinzenz Ferrer von Herisch - I'm unsure what exactly *branobili* or *braenobili* means here. I know that *nobilis* means noble which seems to be the case when looking at the name but the prefix is unknown to me. It is also possible that I misread this part.

Comment: Is it "praenobilis"? I can't really read the script, but that would make sense.

Comment: I'm quite certain that the first letter is not a p as it is lacking a part below the baseline. prae- sounds kind of logical but on the other hand why would a child only become noble when it is older?

Comment: Could it be a capital P? The J in Juvene and the V in Vincentio look like capital letters.

Comment: It could be a capital letter but I think it might be rather a B or something else. If you compare it with the P in Peyrer it looks completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think that it reads "braenobili" in this particular entry. However, as @erstwhile editor mentioned, it might mean "praenobili". In another [entry](http://data.matricula-online.eu/de/oesterreich/gurk/malta/M02_007-1/?pg=22) (4. from the top) a "praenobilis D.na [Domina]" is mentioned.

According to Karl Ernst Georges: Ausführliches lateinisch-deutsches Handwörterbuch. Hannover 81918 (Nachdruck Darmstadt 1998), Band 2, Sp. 1864. (a Latin-German dictionary of 1864, http://www.zeno.org/nid/20002581817) "praenobilis" means "vorzüglich berühmt" (exquisitely famous). This is a quite literal translation. In the end it just means "noble" as I already suspected.